# Spring Data Solr delete operation not working properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-solr

Simple Springboot application using Java + Spring data solr.

Trying to delete the data from solr, it is not working properly.

No error. Simply when we check the data again, it still exists.

```
    @Resource
    private SolrEmployeeRepository repo;

    public ServiceImpl(SolrEmployeeRepository repo) {
            this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean deleteOperation(Employee emp){
        repo.delete(emp);
    }
```

// I tried deleteById(id), deleteAll() etc.. But nothing is working

Note: 
But We are able to add new data into solr. Only problem is delete operation.

Eg:

```
    @Resource
    private SolrEmployeeRepository repo;

    public ServiceImpl(SolrEmployeeRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean saveOperation(List<Employee> emp){
        repo.saveAll(emp);
    }
```

Is there any alternative for deleting? Any different approach?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit more(Repository Interface, Configurations,... )?

Comment: @sivaspon, did you find the solution?